# Qt и решение проблемы межпоточного взаимодействия

Tags: c++, qt

В общем, я много работал с многопоточностью, знаю, как принято решать проблемы с конкурентным доступом к разделяемым ресурсам, будь то файл, консоль, сокет или просто переменная...

Но я не совсем понимаю, с какой стороны подступиться к многопоточности в **Qt**.

Например, я бы хотел решить при помощи **Qt** следующую задачу: фоновый поток осуществляет прием соединения по **TCP/IP** и прием данных, и эти данные необходимо отображать на пользовательском интерфейсе. Конкретно - строить бегущий график, изменять текст нескольких меток. Вот и все.

Подскажите, как это решается в **Qt**? Есть ли при работе с системой слотов и сигналов какие-то особенности в моем случае?

Comment: Конкретно в вашем случае (соединение и чтение данных по TCP/IP) многопоточность и не нужна, есть же [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html), и вот пример - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7923607/3503216

Comment: А вообще потоки в Qt можно начать изучать с этой статьи - https://habr.com/post/150274/

Answer (score 1):

Да, в вашем случае логично использовать систему слотов и сигналов, а особенность/совет: указывайте в **connect** явно пятый параметр:    **Qt::QueuedConnection** или **Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection**